# symfony doctrine three tables one query to Pager (Pagination)?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, pagination, pager

I have three tables:

```
Table 1: Images
------------------------
ID | user_id | title
------------------------
1  |    0    |Image 1
2  |    1    |Image 2 



Table 2: Images_Upload (image_id = Table Images ID)
------------------------
ID | image_id | file
------------------------
1  |    1     |image.png 


Table 3: User
------------------------
ID | username
------------------------
1  |  user1
```

On the Website, the users can Upload an Image. If the User is Logged In, 
and Uploads an Image, then the user_id on Table Image is the users id from Table User. 
If the User is not Logged In, so the user_id is 0 on Table Image.

I want now list the title, show the image and show the username. 
(If the user_id = 0, then i will show "noUsername")

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
 ->select('*,e.title, n.file AS file, IF(e.user_id = 0,"noUsername",k.username) AS username')
  ->from('Images e, ImagesUploads n, User k')
 ->andWhere('e.id = n.id')
 ->andWhere('e.user_id = k.id OR e.user_id not k.id');

 $this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager(
  'Images',
  sfConfig::get('app_max_image')
 );
 $this->pager->setQuery($q);
 $this->pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
 $this->pager->init();
```

I can't get the usernames.

Answer (score 0):

```
------------------------
ID | image_id | file
------------------------
1  |    1     |image1.png
2  |    2     |image2.png
```

Yeah. Sorry. I'm new here. I answered.